# how to find location from text entered in iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am working on the Google map in iOS. I want to search the location based on the text (address) I enter. So, How can I find location (latitude and longitude)
from entered text?

Comment: plz elaborate your question by providing your research links on the subject matter and also **What have you tried**.
You can refere to the following as well:
[How To Ask A Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)    &     
[How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: sometimes I think the stack community is a little harsh on newbies with the down votes. we all got to start somewhere right?

Answer (score 2):

Here is code to get coordinate from address

```
- (void)geocodeFromAddress:(NSString *)address {
    //6
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if([placemarks count]) {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
            NSLog(@"coordinate = (%f, %f)", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error");
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this method, pass address as argument, and CLLocation2D object will be returned with required Latitude and Longitude.

```
+(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocationFromAddressString:(NSString*) addressStr {

    double latitude = 0, longitude = 0;
    NSString *esc_addr =  [addressStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@", esc_addr];
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:req] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    if (result) {
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:result];
        if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"lat\" :" intoString:nil] && [scanner scanString:@"\"lat\" :" intoString:nil]) {
            [scanner scanDouble:&latitude];
            if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"lng\" :" intoString:nil] && [scanner scanString:@"\"lng\" :" intoString:nil]) {
                [scanner scanDouble:&longitude];
            }
        }
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
     GMSCameraUpdate *updatedCamera = [GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:center zoom:19.1];
    [_Map animateWithCameraUpdate:updatedCamera];
    marker.position=center;

}
```

Comment: plz elaborate your question by providing your research links on the subject matter and also **What have you tried**.
You can refere to the following as well:
[How To Ask A Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)    &     
[How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

GLGeocoder will do the job !

Try to adapt this code...

```
NSDictionary *locationDictionary = **SET ADDRESS HERE**;
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressDictionary:locationDictionary completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {   
         if(!error){
             CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0]; //only take the 1st found
             self.latitudeTextField.value = placemark.location.coordinate.latitude;
             self.longitudeTextField.value = placemark.location.coordinate.longitude;
         }
         else{
             // Our geocoder had an error, output a message
            self.result.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString (@"There was a forward geocoding error\n%@", @"Geocoder"), [error localizedDescription]];
         }
     }];
```